# System.Diagnostic Tracing not working with modules added through autofac.config

Tags: configuration, autofac, trace, system.diagnostics

I need help with the Autofac.Configuration extension!

We user Autofac and Autofac.Configuration to add all dependencied to our program. Additionally we use the system.diagnositcs Tracing to Log Methode-Calls, etc (the usual).

Now, we only recently started to use the Autofac.Configuration extension. Until then all messages were written to the output file just as expected. However every class that is only added via the configuration file will not be logged at all. (They do work fine in general, just the logging is not working!)

This is what our configuration file looks like:

```
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "MyClass, MyAssembly",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "MyInterface, MyInterfaceAssembly"
        }
      ],
      "instanceScope": "singleinstance"
    },...
```

This is what our Tracer-Calls look like:

```
private static readonly TraceSource Tracer = new TraceSource("MyCustomName", SourceLevels.Error);

...

Tracer.TraceInformation($"SomeMessage {someInput}");
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Or is this a bug in the Autofac.Configuration extension?

Answer (score 0):

Autofac.Configuration doesn't do anything at all with tracing. If you [search through the source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration) there's not even a reference to tracing anywhere in there.

My guess is that something else has happened. Things I'd look at in your shoes:

- Error in conversion to configuration: Did I forget to register a class that used to be registered? Did I register all the same parameters and everything that used to be code? Anything at all that's different or that I might have missed?
- Unrelated changes: Did I do something else while I was converting to use configuration? Was there other refactoring taking place? Did I pull from the main branch into my task branch and get changes from someone else that may be affecting me?

Unfortunately, you [didn't include a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so there's no way anyone can really help troubleshoot here. However, I can 100% guarantee that the tracing isn't failing due to any bug in the Autofac.Configuration module. It will be something else - either an error in the JSON configuration you've created or some other unrelated change that has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I did look at the source code too and didn't see anything related to tracing either, so thanks for confirming that. :)
I did some more test, as you suggested, and found that the same configuration/setup we do in our "big project" suddenly works just fine in a smaller test version. So yeah I still don't know what causes the problem, but I think I'm getting closer. Thanks for confirming it's not a bug of autfac.configuration! That's a big relieve!

Comment: If you can accept my answer, is appreciate it. That's the "payment" you give people for their answers on StackOverflow - if the answer is right and helps, accept so the answerer gets credit.